# Grunt uglify 0.5 not writing source map?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

So Im trying to add source maps to my js project.  Im using a very simple uglify command, but every time I run the task, I get an error.  Im using uglify 0.5

I have pasted the error and the uglify task below.   It minifies and outputs the file just fine.  It just will not make the source map.  Any help is appreciated.

```
warning: Unable to write "public/dev/output.min.js.map" file (Error code: undefined). Use --force to continue.

 uglify: {
  dev: {
    options: {
    sourceMap: true
  },
  files: {
    'public/dev/output.min.js': ['*/js/angular/angular.js']
  }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be that you are facing this issue: https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/issues/123
I'm still working on getting around it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the github issue mentioned above, it points to a bug in source-map v 0.1.35. For a temporary work around, I force the version of source-map in my package.json file by including it like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "source-map":"0.1.34",
    ...
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    ...
}
```